# PHP GDAL/OGR library

Tags: php, gdal, ogr

I would like to run ogr2ogr in `exec()` function. How to do it? I installed GDAL and I can run ogr2ogr using GDAL Command Prompt but can't use it in `exec()`. Im using XAMPP and I tried to find some libraries which I can add, but didn't find anything like that.

Comment: running through exec() might require that `ogr2ogr` can be found by php, check your (php's) path. I.e if `system('which ogr2ogr')` doesnt print anything, its not findable by php;

`php > system('which foobar');`
which: no foobar in (....)
`php > system('which ls');`
/usr/bin/ls

Comment: watch your permissions too. likely need write access.